# Magento 2.4 : How to change default login page url to custom login page url when click on add to wishlist button for not logged users

Tags: magento2

I have develop another login page for mobile view. i need redirect to custom login page when click on add to wishlist button. this should only for not logged users and only for mobile view.

Comment: 1. Do you need to use this custom login page **only** when redirecting from the "add to wishlist" action ? Or do you need to use this page for all mobile users trying to log in (no matter the page where they come from) ?
2. Isn't it possible dor you to use the same login url for desktop and mobile, and to add responsive design to customize it for mobile users ?